# ggsurvplot risk table not drawing

Tags: r, ggplot2, survminer

This is not so much a question rather than a bug report [which I have now raised on GitHub](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/647). I am posting it here because lots of people are using SO rather than GitHub to get help. And maybe someone of you has found/ will find a workaround for it.

`survminer::ggsurvplot` doesn't seem to draw risk tables any longer. It must have been a recent update with something (I cannot say of what!), because it used to work until some time ago (I cannot say when it stopped working).

This is a reprex of the example code in `?ggsurvplot`!!! I just added `risk.table = T`.

```r
library(survminer)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggpubr
library(survival)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'survival'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:survminer':
#> 
#>     myeloma

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = T)
#> Error in as.character(call[[1]]): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-14 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur 11.7.6
#>  system   x86_64, darwin20
#>  ui       X11
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  ggplot2     * 3.4.4.9000 2023-11-19 [1] local
#>  ggpubr      * 0.6.0      2023-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  survival    * 3.5-7      2023-08-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  survminer   * 0.4.9      2021-03-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)

#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Works fine using `ggplot2 3.5.0` (which seems to be the only difference)

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Mysterious... I will immediately upgrade ggplot then :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks user Stefan who reminded me of the importance of always keeping all your packages up to date! (I also only then realised that I was still running ggplot2's Dev version).

```r
suppressMessages({
  library(survminer)
 library(survival)})
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = T)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-14 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur 11.7.6
#>  system   x86_64, darwin20
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8

#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source

#>  ggplot2     * 3.5.0   2024-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  ggpubr      * 0.6.0   2023-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  survival    * 3.5-8   2024-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#>  survminer   * 0.4.9   2021-03-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)

#> 
#>  [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```